# How to remove Directory name from the URL using .htaccess for localhost

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting, xampp

I want to change the URL from:

```
http://localhost/rootdirectory/portfolio/project-1.php
```

To:

```
http://localhost/rootdirectory/project-1
```

I have used below code currently but it's not working

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

This code is rewriting my URL as `http://localhost/project-1` instead of
`http://localhost/rootdirectory/project-1`.

Comment: So have it redirect to `/rootdirectory/$1` then …?

Comment: Or to `$1`, if this .htaccess itself is supposed to be located in `/rootdirectory` already.

Comment: .htaccess is already in the rootdirectory

Answer (score 0):

> This code is rewriting my URL as `http://localhost/project-1` instead of `http://localhost/rootdirectory/project-1`.

The code you posted is "redirecting", not "rewriting", the URL from `/portfolio/<project>` to `/<project>`.

From your URL example it looks like you should instead be *rewriting* the URL from `/rootdirectory/<project>` to `/rootdirectory/portfolio/<project>.php` (assuming you have already changed the URL in your application). If the `.htaccess` file is located at `/rootdirectory/.htaccess` (as stated in comments) then you would need something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)$ portfolio/$1.php [L]
```

And *remove* the `RewriteBase /` directive altogether.

Comment: it still showing directory name **portfolio** in url like rootdirectory/portfolio/project all i want is that the directory name portfolio should not me in url

Comment: You need to actually change the URL that appears in the HTML source (and consequently appears in the browser address bar). `.htaccess` won't do this for you. You need to actually change your links to `/rootdirectory/project-1`. You then use `.htaccess` to _internally rewrite_ the request from `/rootdirectory/project-1` to `/rootdirectory/portfolio/<project>.php` - as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to the folder that contains all the files for your site.
2. form your cpanel copy all the files to your Public_html folder.

Comment: The OP is wanting to implement "pretty" URLs, by changing the URL structure only, not the underlying file structure. No actual files should be moved anywhere.